# which understanding is correct,the translation from a reference book or my understanding?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, difference

I'm preparing for IELTS test. And there is one sentence in the listening tape I don't quite understand. Below is the tapescript:

> And one of the first-year students I interviewed wanted reassurance that no names would be traceable from the answers. **I was so surprised, because they think nothing of telling you about themselves and their opinions in seminar groups!**

I understand the first sentence, which means that specific student is very cautious. However, as to the second sentence in bold, the reference book translates this sentence into Chinese like

> they are reluctant to say anything about themselves

However, I check several dictionaries on google about the meaning of "think nothing of ",and they say that this phrase means

1. find it easy to do something
2. Give little consideration to

So, in my opinion, the meaning of the second sentence should be something like

> they are willing to tell you about themselves and their opinions

which understanding is correct? Really look forward to seeing your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right with your understanding. And this is a reason of reaction of author: "I was surprised." But this is not clear without comparing of meanings of sentences.

Comment: Yes, the OP is right; it's perfectly clear to a native speaker. Students readily talk about themselves in seminars, so the author was surprised that one of them wanted their name kept secret in a test.